# How do I increase a number over and over again in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, increment

I want to increase a number for every new call so instead of bonbons(x-10) should be bonbons(x-20), bonbons(x-30) and so on.

```
module AufgabeBonbons where

bonbons :: Int -> Int
bonbons x | x <= 550 && x >= 10 = 1 + bonbons(x-10)
            |otherwise = 0
```

I tried to create a new function but I am not so sure if this is the right way to handle this problem.

Comment: Increase with *what*? The problem statement is not very clear.

Comment: So for every new call the value which is currently x-10 should increase to x-20, x-30 ... up to x-100

Comment: So you want to generate a list? It might help if you provide some sample input/output and explain how the input maps on the output

Comment: Okay so I have an amount of cents x and I want to buy candy. The candy each cost 10 cents, 20 cents and so on up to 1 euro. I can only buy one candy of each kind (each centkind) and  I want to know how many candies I can buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following description:

> Okay so I have an amount of cents x and I want to buy candy. The candy each cost 10 cents, 20 cents and so on up to 1 euro. I can only buy one candy of each kind (each centkind) and I want to know how mandy candies I can buy.

You are essentially looking for the largest *n* for which the equation holds:

[image]

This is a known series that can be solved as:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Indeed, image that we have 30 cents, then the result is (√5×√125-5)/10=2.

We thus can implement this as:

```
bonbons :: Int -> Int
bonbons x = min 10 (floor ((sqrt (5 * (4*x'+5)) - 5) / 10))
  where x' = fromIntegral x
```

> I want to increase a number for every new call so instead of `bonbons(x-10)`, should be `bonbons(x-20)`, `bonbons(x-30)` and so on.

We can work with a variable that specifies the amount for the next bonbon:

```
bonbons :: Int -> Int
bonbons = go 10
  where go m n
           | m <= n && m < 100 = 1 + go (m+10) (n-m)
           | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: The formulas don't render very well in dark mode, with transparent background and black text.

Comment: The loop in your final implementation can also be implemented by combining premade standard-library loops: `bonsbons x = length . takeWhile (<=x) . scanl1 (+) $ [10,20..100]`.